# Greater than (gte) query in MongoEngine for EmbeddedDocumentListField

Tags: django, python-2.7, mongoengine

So this is how my models look like. Class A is having an EmbeddedDocumentListField of SlotTime.

```
class SlotTime(EmbeddedDocument):
    # this is having minutes like 780 for 1pm.
    start_time = IntField(required=True)
    end_time = IntField(required=True)

 class A(Document):
    name = StringField(primary_key=True)
    slot_hours = EmbeddedDocumentListField(SlotTime)
```

SlotTime has a list of objects with start and end time value.
    `[<SlotTime: SlotTime object>,<SlotTime: SlotTime object>]`
    and now I want to make a query that will return me the results that have start_time greater that to a given value.
want a somthing simliar to this query:`A.objects.get(name__exact='xyz').slot_hours.filter(start_time__gte=780)`

tried this but this is returning all the value. `A.objects.filter(name__exact='xyz',slot_hours__start_time__gte=780)[0].slot_hours`

Can someone please help me in how I can do this? Thank you!

Comment: Please add code for `OrderTime`.

Comment: edited the code. @RahulGupta

Comment: [Related GitHub issue](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/1291)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the schema that you provided, you could achieve that simply with the `__gte` operator. See below:

```
A.objects(name__exact='xyz', slot_hours__start_time__gte=780)
A.objects(name__exact='xyz').filter(slot_hours__start_time__gte=780)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MongoEngine currently supports further filtering out the `EmbeddedDocuments` received using the `.filter()` query you used above. That's why accessing `slot_hours` returns all the `SlotTime` objects for that object instead of only those `SlotTime` objects having `start_time` greater than 780.

To do that, you will have to manually filter out the objects using list comprehensions.

```
# perform filtering and get the first 'A' object
obj = A.objects.filter(name__exact='xyz',slot_hours__start_time__gte=780)[0]

# get the relavent 'SlotTime' objects
slot_time_objs = [x for x in obj.slot_hours if x.start_time >= 780]
```

Comment: Done this workaround already, but I was not sure that whether can be achieved by the query or not.

Comment: I am afraid currently its not possible in MongoEngine.